# Get selected parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, bids

In a Report (Business Intelligence Report Project), I have a dataSet with this query:
select * from order where MonthId in (@MonthId)

In another dataSet I have a query returning all Months from Month Table, and bind it to @MonthId parameter, and the parameter is enable for MultipleValue.
So to this point in Preview mode a combobox is listing the months and user can select one or more month(es) and see the orders at that month by clicking view report button.
No my question is:
How can I show the selected months that user selects, in a textBox in my report?
Actually I want to show the selected parameters texts in a a textBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

=Join(Parameters!monthID.Label,",")